# Garmin Nuvi 1350 GPS

Tags: 12.04, gps

I have a Garmin Nuvi 1350 GPS and would like to know if I could download maps from the garmin Website like I do in Windows. In Windows, you need the Garmin Express app, but no such thing seems to exist in Ubuntu 12.04.

Answer (score 0):

You could always use WINE and install the Garmin Express app.

Start by going to the Software Center and installing the latest version of Wine. Then, download and install the Garmin Express exe file. Wine should run it and install it.

Note, however, that there are sometimes dependency errors. To fix this, you need to manually check all dependancies of Garmin Express. It should work though.